# Will setting date.timezone affecting php script?

Tags: php

I have a simple question regarding data.timezone.
My company server has been long run and I have notice they didn't set any date.timezone in php.ini before. So I would like to make change to php.ini, but I worry it will affecting other script. Do or will it affect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the scripts that use it and whether or not they work with datetime objects.

Comment: If it aint broke don't fix it!

Comment: There must be a default timezone even if they didnt set one in php.ini

Comment: @Dagon I would absolutely hate to have you as a server admin where I write code =P If her hasn't written the code, and there is a lot of it, he really shouldn't change anything now - at least not without letting every programmer that uses that server know that he is changing that setting.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ If i remember correctly, depending on the PHP version, it would default to UTC if not set.

Comment: @Jon - We changed it from GMT to UTC to please the yanks!

Comment: Hi everyone, all of our script is using the same timezone, so will it still affecting the scripts?

Comment: @Jon Just want to reduce the warning generate from Apache error log and avoiding to include "date_default_timezone_set" in PHP script everytime we script it.

Comment: @Info if they are all using the same timezone and don't do any conversions, you will be fine setting it. =]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all! Problem solved as Jon spoken!

> if they are all using the same timezone and don't do any conversions, you will be fine setting it. =]